# Apache- How to search for files before directories?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, directory

I have php file named `tennis.php` on my apache web server. my `.htaccess`, with the contents: 
`RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php`
This successfully works, and allows me to go to 'mywebsite.com/tennis' and access tennis.php. Then, I added a directory in the same location as the tennis.php file, named `tennis`, and when I go to 'mywebsite.com/tennis' it shows up as a directory listing. I want it to prioritize the *files* over directories. Any ways to do so? Thanks!

Comment: Did my answer work for you? Please accept it if it did. And perhaps upvote it? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, stop disabling your rule if the request exists as a directory:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
```

Comment: Strange. Doesn't seem to be working if I delete that line, do I need to do more than a 'sudo service apache2 restart'?

Comment: No, nothing more, not even that if it's in a .htaccess file. Is a forward slash being added after `tennis`? Try clearing your browser cache which has likely cached the redirect from `tennis` to `tennis/` that Apache generates for directories. With the above in place it shouldn't get redirected, but you have it cached.